# cryptsetup: create encrypted image file that an older version of losetup can open and mount

Tags: linux, encryption

I have a need to create an encrypted image file with cryptsetup, and be able to open the image file on an older system using the encryption option for losetup.

the older system cannot change, and uses a script to open an archive with this command within a python script (I have the password that was within the file losetup was using):

`losetup -p %d -e aes /dev/loop0 /mnt/encMount' % (fdes)`

I am trying to figure out what settings to use with cryptsetup such that losetup will be able to open the image file successfully.

here are the two versions being used:

cryptsetup 2.3.2

losetup from util-linux 2.22.2

I have tried the following cipher options and none have worked so far, or I'm going about it completely wrong

`cryptsetup open /media/sda1/aes-cbc-essivmd5.img encryptedfile --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:md5 -h md5 --key-file /tmp/p`

`cryptsetup open /media/sda1/aes-cbc-essivsha256.img encryptedfile --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 -h sha256 --key-file /tmp/p`

`cryptsetup open /media/sda1/aes-cbc-plainmd5.img encryptedfile --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-plain:md5 -h md5 --key-file /tmp/p`

`cryptsetup open /media/sda1/aes-cbc-plainsha1.img encryptedfile --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-plain:sha1 -h sha1 --key-file /tmp/p`

`cryptsetup open /media/sda1/aes-cbc-plainsha256.img encryptedfile --type plain --cipher aes-cbc-plain:sha256 -h sha256 --key-file /tmp/p`

Thanks!

Comment: `--type loopaes`? also check the manpage and cryptsetup FAQ on loop-aes. are you still using the wrong password from your other question? if your password was a fd.fileno, try a number from 0 .. 100

Answer (score 0):

@user566330 there's sort of a bug/ambiguity in losetup 2.22 implementation where it only picks up the first 31 bytes of the key no matter what you provide to it on the command line or through a key file.

https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/stable/v2.22/lib/loopdev.c#L1091 (see the definition and usage of lo_encrypt_key and LO_KEY_SIZE)

Such an observation was made even by the maintainers when they removed encryption support from losetup in v2.22+: https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/5cf05c71472bf7230075cbdcd5cd6eb12b1d3654

With that in mind if you try to use a 31 byte key between cryptsetup/losetup it should ideally work. Happy hunting!